# Incomprehensible FPGA error

Tags: intel-fpga

I try and upload my design, which worked previously, using quartus prime 17.1 to an Altera DE2-115.

It fails like this: `Error (209015): Can't configure device. Expected JTAG ID code 0x020F10DD for device 1, but found JTAG ID code 0x020B40DD. Make sure the location of the target device on the circuit board matches the device's location in the device chain in the Chain Description File (.cdf).`

What does it mean?

Comment: Check your pin mappings of the top level entity whether all are mapped or not.

Answer (score 1):

It means the programming software thinks the the device it's trying to talk to isn't the device it's looking for. Could be caused by a number of things. Maybe you selected the wrong FPGA in your project settings. Maybe JTAG configuration is wrong.

Comment: Where are those "project settings"? I can't change something that I can't even find.

Comment: There is to be somewhere to select the part number for the FPGA that you're using. It looks like the project may set to target a different part. In which case, even if the programmer wrote the bitstream to the FPGA, it would not work.